# Event fire and Workflow Attach to External List?

Tags: bcs, external-list

What is the best way approach to attach workflow and Event Receiver on External List?
How to store Directly External Data to SharePoint Custom List?List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know the external list has about 25 limitations, because the data is stored into external data base. In your case you faced with these limitations:

1. Workflows cannot be attached
2. You cannot attach event receiver

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408903/can-an-external-list-have-event-receivers) you can read

> A workaround seems to be to create the external content type in Visual
>   Studio. That way you can add some code to the create method to do
>   additional things.

but I have not find any examples. I found out that in SharePoint 2013 you can use app to solve this issue. See [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163976.aspx) for more details.